# Why does Python change the function's arity if I don't use the arguments?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a very weird python behaviour at hand.

Invoking the following function via Airflow (AirBnB's scheduler framework)'s `PythonOperator` mysteriously fails with `TypeError: my_fun() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`:

```
def my_fun(a, **kwargs):
    print('line')
```

But if I use the arguments like this:

```
def my_fun(a, **kwargs):
    # At run time it appears the framework is 
    # giving this function 20 arguments.
    # Without these following two meaningless lines, 
    # python doesn't think my function can take those
    assert(a is not None)
    assert (kwargs is not None)
    print('line')
```

It runs fine! If I use a function that takes no argument, it fails with `takes exactly 0 argument (20 given)`. Here is a bit more detailed stacktrace:

```
ERROR - my_fun() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/venv/airflow/bin/airflow", line 6, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/root/venv/airflow/src/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 17, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/root/venv/airflow/src/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 287, in test
    ti.run(force=True, ignore_dependencies=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/root/venv/airflow/src/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 978, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/root/venv/airflow/src/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 65, in execute
    return_value = self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
```

I'm completely flabbergast. Even more so because a seemingly identical construct runs fine:

```
def my_thing(a, **kwargs):
    thing()
```

What could it be?

EDIT
Here is the task setup in Airflow:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 4, 25)
}

dag = DAG('some_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1),
          max_active_runs=1,
          concurrency=1)

def runs_fine(execution_date, **kwargs):
    print('fine')

runs_fine_task = PythonOperator(task_id='run_fine',
                                    concurrency=1,
                                    max_active_runs=1,
                                    retries=0,
                                    provide_context=True,
                                    python_callable=runs_fine,
                                    dag=dag)

def fails(execution_date, **kwargs):
    print('fails')

fails_task = PythonOperator(task_id='I_fail',
                               concurrency=1,
                               max_active_runs=1,
                               retries=0,
                               provide_context=True,
                               python_callable=fails,
                               dag=dag)
```

Comment: what's your task/dag setup look like? what are you setting as the python callable in the task? also, are you setting provide_context to True?

Comment: you could also try doing something like `def f(*args, **kwargs): print(args, kwargs)` to see what the heck is going on.

Comment: @acushner: Added the task setup code. I specified provide_context=True

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `runs_fine` and `fails` in the last example code..?

Comment: @poke: I know, to my eyes there isn't any, which leaves me baffled.

Comment: maybe change both `runs_fine` and `fails` to take `*args, **kwargs` and then log out what gets put into both.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that I gave up and just left the assertion that apparently makes it work, for whatever reason. I'll report back when I find out what was happening.